# Can I have a Feedback on my Edits?

Tags: discussion

I posted a previous question "Can newbies get feedback from senior community members". The Feedback were so encouraging. There it was mentioned that I can ask for feedback at any time. So that's why I am seeking a feedback.

I could edit more than 700 posts. Thanks for your guide.

I have something to ask also. Certain questions are not easily readable. People who read and do answer are doing it voluntarily. So if they are not eye catching the content, they are having least probability to get answers. It is the reality. Certain questions have large details, stacked. But the problem is not strange. But they haven't got answers. Would it be necessary to break them into paragraphs ?

Seeking for some feedback.

Comment: I think just paragraph breaks are fine edits, as long as they don't leave out glaringly bad problems.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: I didn't get what you are asking? You may use [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on Meta SO to post and experiment with markdown.. Otherwise, let us know through Meta/[Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and we would help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have approved several of your edits (you are indeed making many of them better readable).

The first point to look for feedback are the comments you get on rejected edits - often when I reject an edit I say how the edit could be improved to make it really useful.

Another way for improving your edits is to look what a user did who "improved" your edit (you will see this in the edit history of the post when your suggest has been approved my "community").

Nearly every question has typos and grammar problems. When you edit a question don't concentrate on the obvious problems only (creating paragraph breaks is a good thing™), try to fix additional errors as well, then your edits will (most likely) be approved.

While I was beginning to learn how make good edits I made a habit of looking at every suggest I had made a day or two later (To see if it got approved and who rejected it (also the reason why it got rejected)).

Comment: Thanks for your advices.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela also, is not necessary to add a space before `?` and `!`. English doesn't have such rules.

Comment: Ok. I will follow. Thanks.